# Can't seem to rid of the error message no matter what I've tried. From "Hello! Python" book

Tags: python, python-3.5

Here's the error I'm getting when I try to run the code below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JPagz95/Documents/Hunt_the_Wumpus_3.py", line 76, in <module>
    visit_cave(0)
  File "/Users/JPagz95/Documents/Hunt_the_Wumpus_3.py", line 15, in visit_cave
    unvisited_caves.remove(cave_number)
AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I understand how the int and range don't have those functions, but they shouldn't be defined that way originally.  I realize it's a lot of code but I feel like the problem might be in more than one place.  This code is based off of chapter to of the "Hello! Python" book if that helps.  I would appreciate any help I can get!

```
from random import choice

cave_numbers = range(0,20)
unvisited_caves = range(0,20)
visited_caves = []

def create_tunnel(cave_from, cave_to):
    """ create a tunnel between cave_from and cave_to """
    caves[cave_from].append(cave_to)
    caves[cave_to].append(cave_from)

def visit_cave(cave_number):
    """ mark a cave as visited """
    visited_caves.append(cave_number)
    unvisited_caves.remove(cave_number)

def choose_cave(cave_list):
    """ pick a cave from a list, provided that the
    cave has less than 3 tunnels """
    cave_number = choice(cave_list)
    while len(caves[cave_number]) >= 3:
        cave_number = choice(cave_list)
    return cave_number

def print_caves():
    """ print out the current cave structure """
    for number in cave_numbers:
        print (number, ":", caves[number])
    print ('----------')

def setup_caves(cave_numbers):
    """ create a starting list of caves """
    caves = []
    for number in cave_numbers:
        caves.append([number])
    return caves

def link_caves():
    """ make sure all of the caves are connected with two way tunnels"""
    while unvisited_caves != []:
        this_cave = choose_cave(visited_caves)
        next_cave = choose_cave(unvisited_caves)
    create_tunnel(this_cave, next_cave)
    visit_cave(next_cave)

def finish_caves():
    """ link the rest of the caves with one way tunnels """
    for cave in cave_numbers:
        while len(caves[cave]) < 3:
            passage_to = choose_cave(cave_numbers)
            caves[cave].append(passage_to)

def print_location(player_location):
    """ tell the player about where they are """
    print ("You are in a cave ", player_location)
    print ("From here you can see caves: ")
    print (caves[player_location])
    if wumpus_location in caves[player_location]:
        print ("I smell a wumpus!")

def get_next_location():
    """ Get the player's next location """
    print ("Which cave next?")
    player_input = input(">")
    if (not player_input.isdigit() or
        int(player_input) not in
            caves[player_location]):
        print(player_input + "?")
        print ("That's not a direction I can see!")
        return none
    else:
        return int(player_input)

caves = setup_caves(cave_numbers)

visit_cave(0)
print_caves()
link_caves()
print_caves()
finish_caves()

wumpus_location = choice(cave_numbers)
player_location = choice(cave_numbers)
while player_location == wumpus_location:
    player_location = choice(cave_numbers)

print ("Welcome to Hunt the Wumpus!")
print ("You can see ", len(cave_numbers), " caves")
print ("To play, just type the number")
print ("of the cave you wish to enter next")

while True:
    print_location(player_location)
    new_location = get_next_location()
    if new_location != None:
        player_location = new_location
    if player_location == wumpus_location:
        print ("Aargh! You got eaten by a wumpus!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you declare as

```
unvisited_caves = list(range(0,20))
```

by default `range(0,20)` returns an object that "generates" the values of 0 to 20. It is much more efficient because it just needs to remember the start and end values (0 and 20) along the step size (in your case 1).

Contrast this with a **list** that must store every value from 0 to 20, and you can remove individual values from this list.

Comment: it just outputs the cave as a list rather than showing the sequence of caves available to the player

Comment: is the error on the same line? It's possible you have a similar issue somewhere else.

Comment: @JordanPagni You've got a few `while` loops that never end. It's getting hung up in `link_caves()` because `unvisited_caves != []` is true, and it will keep doing the instructions within the while loop until it breaks (which it never does). Looks like you're going to have similar problems with your other while loops so you'll need to check them out as well.

Comment: sorry took me so long to answer martin and vesche.  at Martin the lines are the same but the problem is different: "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list".  @vesche ill have to look through it and maybe check back in tomorrow.  im new to stack exchange and python so these fixes dont come easily :)

Comment: @JordanPagni, well there's your problem :) Make sure you check that that item is in the list before you remove it.